# Creating a consolidated e-mail alert for SQL batch job failures

Tags: sql-server, email, ssms

So here is the scenario. On one of my primary SSMS boxes, I have roughly 100 replication batch jobs. These batch jobs, replicate a range of static data from a "Master" DB down to each individual DB. So there is a batch job, per DB. When a new Database is created, a new batch job is created.

The batch job follows a naming convention, below is an example

```
PG-APP03-ORIGINS_Master-PG-APP03-100
```

So we can see the server is PG-APP03 and that it is the ORIGINS_Master Database, however the rest of the job name doesn't quickly let me see the Database affected. If I drill into the steps of this job, I see the following

```
-Subscriber [PG-APP03] -SubscriberDB [ORIGINS_9107L1] 
-Publisher [PG-APP03]  
-Distributor [PG-APP03] 
-DistributorSecurityMode 1 
-PublisherDB [ORIGINS_Master]
```

so from this, I can see the "Subscriber" is a database name that I recognise.

However I can have on occasion up to 20 of these jobs fail first thing in the morning. I disabled the individual email alerts, because the jobnames arn't identifiable. So each morning I come in, view the job failures, and have to drill into Step 2 of each job to find the subscriber name.

I'm looking for ways where I can collate all the failures together, identify them by the Subscriber, and send that in one e-mail to me.

Not only can I use this to then work through fixing the issues quicker, I can send that email to some key people as a notification that the DB's are not accurate until replication is fixed.

I've been routing around some tables in the DB and can find places where the jobs exists, where I can see the steps, but I'm really struggling to put this all together.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK so I've created a script for which the output is basically what I want. I've passed it over to a colleague who does our Sys Packages and stuff, and he says he can get it running automated for me and firing the results into an email. So think I might have it sorted!

Comment: The code is messy, but incase someone stumbles across the question here is what I did

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I wrote that gave me the output required

```
USE MSDB
GO

DECLARE @time INT
SET @time = cast(convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) as int)

SELECT DISTINCT 
   a.Name,
   b.server,
   CASE WHEN c.step_name ='Run Agent.' THEN 'Replication' END AS 'Step Name',
   CASE WHEN c.run_status ='0' THEN 'Failed' END AS 'Run Status',
   c.run_date,
   CASE WHEN b.subsystem ='Distribution' THEN SUBSTRING(b.command,38,15)
   ELSE '' END AS 'Subscriber'
FROM sysjobs AS a
INNER JOIN sysjobsteps AS b
ON a.job_id = b.job_id
INNER JOIN sysjobhistory AS c
ON a.job_id=c.job_id
WHERE c.run_status ='0'
AND c.step_id ='2'
AND c.run_date = @time
AND b.subsystem = 'Distribution'
```

So I have the Subscriber column, where I will be able to make out what Db in question has a replication problem

[image: Result]